# How do I make Victorian looking minifigures?

Tags: minifigures

I want to do a Victorian style station to go with my steam trains. I've got some great ideas for the building and accessories, but I'm not sure about the people. How can I make Victorian-looking minifigures?

BTW: I don't want to permanently modify bricks, but would consider the use of stickers.

Ideas I already have:

Headgear:

- Top hats
- Deerstalker
- Peaked cap for railway workers

Sadly, the Lego bowlers are either blue with a flower or grey with a question mark - not really suitable.

Head:

- For males, any that have weird facial hair (there are surprisingly many) and/or round glasses

Torso:

- Smart suits. I've read that shirtsleeves were considered unseemly.

Any other ideas?

--- Edit ---

As an example of what I have in mind, here's a railway worker I made from parts I got from PAB. Of course, I'll need passangers and other staff, too. And I'm more than happy to order individual parts from bricklink (as long as my wife agrees!).

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A number of the minifigs from the [Adventures theme](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Adventurers) would fit the bill in terms of round glasses and facial hair, especially the Dr Kilroy character:

[image: Dr Kilroy's Car]

They also have versions with suits, etc.

There's also a ["Detective" figure](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8805-11) in the Minifigures Series 5 with the classic Deer Stalker hat that resembles the fictional detective Sherlock Holmes.

[image: Detective Collectable Minifigure]

There are also top hats available in Series 1 with the Magician and Ringmaster.

Comment: The Adventures theme is a great source of inspiration - I've never really looked at them before. You're certainly right about the facial hair!

Answer (score 7):

The [10199-1 Winter Village Toy Shop](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10199-1) set contains two very good Victorian carol singer minifigures:

[image]

[image]

Other sets in this series have some quite good period clothing, here's one from the bakery (10216-1)

[image]

Comment: Heh, love the use of a double cape on the female singer :)

Comment: These are great... except for the picture of a jet plane on the male carol singer's jacket. Apart from that, these would be a great for parts.